# Should i check that i assign different value to @Published property?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have simple example of code in which i update `@State` and `@Published` property with same value (on button click). Now i see that then i assign the same value to `@State` there is no body call of view. But then i assign to `@Published` property then there is call on each assign. I know that it might be fast but still there might be an unnecessary calls to body of view.

So should i check that i actually change value of `@Published` property or there is some other ways?

```swift
class Object: ObservableObject {
    @Published var state: Bool = false
    
    func setState() {
        state = false
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var state: Bool = false
    @ObservedObject var obj = Object()

    var body: some View {
        print(Self._printChanges())
        return VStack {
            Text("\(String(state))")
            Button("Tap") {
                self.state = false
                obj.setState()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output on tap clicks (3 times):

```
ContentView: _obj changed.
()
ContentView: _obj changed.
()
ContentView: _obj changed.
()
```

Comment: This sounds like premature optimisation to me...

Comment: I don't know. I have a part in my code. I check some condition which usually `false` and very rarely `true`.  Now i have updates on each `false` set. The call to the big body of view seems like wasting resources. On the other hand i can make very simple check.  And it seems strange that this works fine for `@State` but not for `@Published`

Comment: Well, you can use Instruments to measure the performance of your app with the check vs without the check. And no, it's not strange. That's just how `State` and `Published` behave.

Comment: `@State` is internal for the View but an `@ObservedObject` is an external resource so that is why they are handled differently and why the View can keep track of any changes of a `@State` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SwiftUI is declarative, so it could be argued that this specific behaviour is an implementation detail and I would not worry about it.
Just because SwiftUI is calling `body` does not necessarily mean that your UI is being redrawn.
Indeed, if each view has the same ["Identity"](https://www.wwdcnotes.com/notes/wwdc21/10022/) with unchanged data, you do not need to worry about additional SwiftUI draw calls.
The system will know nothing has changed and won't incur UI overhead.

You don't need to work on patching around this unless you have specifically profiled this as being a performance bottleneck in your app.
Don't optimize anything unless you have good reason to, otherwise you're just wasting time (as there may be other bottlenecks to work on first).

Answer (score 1):

Even though the view is not going to redraw, your concerns are indeed valid. In certain scenarios, such as when you have a shared view model across multiple views or if the computation of the body is complex, unnecessary frequent body computations caused by setting the same value can slightly contribute to animation hitches or lags, especially if it happens during animations or gestures and layout is complex and highly dynamic.

To deal with this I made the following custom property wrapper which assigns and publish new value only if it is different:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

@propertyWrapper
struct PublishedOnChange<Value: Equatable> {
    private var value: Value
    private weak var objectWillChange: ObservableObjectPublisher?

    var wrappedValue: Value {
        get { value }
        set {
            guard value != newValue else { return }
            value = newValue
            objectWillChange?.send()
        }
    }

    init(wrappedValue: Value) {
        self.value = wrappedValue
    }

    mutating func assignPublisher(_ publisher: ObservableObjectPublisher) {
        objectWillChange = publisher
    }
}
```

**USAGE:**

```
class ExampleViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @PublishedOnChange var someVar: Int = 0

    init() {
        _someVar.assignPublisher(objectWillChange)
    }
}
```

This way you can simply apply `@PublishedOnChange` to any property you need. It works like the `@Published` wrapper, except it won't trigger view update if you assign the same value.

Answer (score 0):

Your concern is valid. This problem can be partially solved with the `@Observable` macro of **iOS 17.0**, which is said to be the alternative of `ObservableObject` protocol by apple.

```swift
import SwiftUI

@Observable
class Object {
    var state: Bool = false
    
    func setState() {
        state = false
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var state: Bool = false
    @State var obj = Object()

    var body: some View {
        print(Self._printChanges())
        return VStack {
            Text("State: \(String(state))")

            Button("Tap") {
                self.state = false
                obj.setState()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you don't use `obj.state` in the view so the view body does not re-calculate while pressing `Tap`.

**What it solves:**

- If your view does not use the `obj.state` inside your view then your view will not be recalculated. So if you have concern of multiple views getting re-calculated because of any Published property change than this update can solve this.

**What it cannot solve:**

- If your view uses the `obj.state` property then the view will be re-calculated even if you keep assigning the same value. To solve this you should handle your data properly so that it doesn’t assign the same values.